# How to overcome AChartEngine ordering points by x-coordinates

Tags: android, plot, achartengine, interpolation

I am using AChartEngine to display an XY series that looks somewhat like a traditional parabola rotated 90 degrees clockwise. As you can see in this scatter plot, the series may have more than one y-point for a given x-coordinate; x-coordinates of successive points initially decrease then increase while y-coordinates always increase:

[AChartEngine Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9BJG.png)

Now, if I change the chart type to line or cubic line, it gets garbled by the interpolator -- here is a zoomed leftmost part:

[AChartEngine Line Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wUCN.png)

It looks like AChartEngine orders the points in the series by their x-coordinates before plotting. This is apparently necessary because "starting from Android 3.0, it is no longer fine to draw stuff outside the screen." I have trouble buying this reason because if that was the case, the scatter chart could not be rendered correctly (and it is).

I'd rather not rewrite the library to remove point sorting. Has anyone come across this problem and figured out how to overcome it through API calls? If a change in the library is necessary, I would appreciate a piece of code.

Comment: I figured out a workaround that solely uses the API: Split the XYSeries into multiple sub-series, in each of which x-coordinates are monotonic. In the above case, this resulted in two sub-series added to the dataset and plotted with identical attributes, so that they look like one. To avoid gaps in the plot, the last point of a sub-series must also be the first point of the next sub-series.